# Deploy osgi bundles to Geronimo remotly

Tags: java, deployment, osgi, geronimo

We have some custom repository which contains different builds (set of osgi bundles). There are any Geronimo 3 remote servers. I should by a command get some build from repository and make hot deploy to a set of stands. It maybe existing tool or java api. As I know Cargo don't work with remote Geronimo. I will be grateful for any suggestion.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [John Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Comment: I think the question is not perfect but also not that bad. What exactly do you think is missing or wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Geronimo 3 is based on apache karaf. So the mechanisms provided by karaf may be of help.

1. Connect to the ssh console and use commands like bundle:install or feature:install
2. Use the remote JMX port and the MBeans provided there. Again you have the choice between installing bundles or features

In both cases bundles and features can be refered with http or mvn uri. I personally normally use the mvn uris that karaf also uses internally.

So the process is to first build your bundles/features to a maven repository and then trigger the install command and access the mvn repo you deployed to.

You can add you own maven repo in the etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.cfg.

Comment: Thank you. I prefer programmatic way. I'll try MBeans